# Removing a Google maps Circle/shape

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a Circle using the google.maps.Circle() method. This all works fine and dandy, but how can I remove said circle?

My code:

```
var populationOptionsAgain = {
  strokeColor: "#c4c4c4",
  strokeOpacity: 0.35,
  strokeWeight: 0,
  fillColor: "#ffffff",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: results[0].geometry.location,
  radius: 40000
};
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptionsAgain);
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to call the [setMap](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays) method on the Circle object to null:

```
cityCircle.setMap(null);
```

Comment: @Neurofluxation No problems :) It is a bit counter intuitive at first (google maps v2 did it the other way), but I think it actually makes sense once you are used to it.

Comment: how to remove all drawing or multiple circle ..?

Answer (score 12):

To remove a circle from the map, call the `setMap()` method passing `null` as the argument.

```
circle.setMap(null);
```

Note that the above method does not delete the circle. It simply removes the circle from the map. If instead you wish to delete the circle, you should remove it from the map, and then set the circle itself to `null`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circle_remove

Comment: Assigning to null doesn't "delete the circle" either, it just reassigns value of the reference.

Comment: The right way to say it would be "lose all references to the circle object". Setting null to all of them would work.

Comment: how to remove all drawing or multiple circle ..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove events listeners too, not just hiding the circle, in-fact `circle.setMap(null)` will just hide the circle

```
function remove_circle(circle) {
    // remove event listers
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(circle, 'click_handler_name');
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(circle, 'drag_handler_name');
    circle.setRadius(0);
    // if polygon:
    // polygon_shape.setPath([]); 
    circle.setMap(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API has been updated.
You can now directly use the following code :

```
circle.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(this.circle!== undefined || this.circle)
          this.circle.setMap(null);
```